# Make IntelliJ aware of links to Java elements in XML files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a custom XML format that links to Java resources. For the sake of simplicity let's assume my XML file would look like this:

```xml
<root>
  <java-class>my.fully.qualified.class.name</java-class>
</root>
```

Eventually my references will be somewhat more complicated. It will not contain the fully qualified class name directly and I will need some logic to resolve the correct class, but I want to keep the example as simple as possible here.

Now I want it to be possible to Strg+Click on the element's text and want IntelliJ to carry me to the .java file, just like it is possible in Spring-XML files. In the [IDEA Plugin Development FAQ](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Plugin+Development+FAQ) there is a link called "[How do I add custom references to Java elements in XML files?](http://www.intellij.net/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=196522)" which so much sounds like exactly what I need. Unfortunately it links to a discussion where someone is more or less done implementing something like this, having some minor problems. Nevertheless I understood that I probably need to write an implementation of the interface com.intellij.psi.PsiReference. Googling for "PsiReference" and "IntelliJ" or "IDEA" unfortunately did not bring up any tutorials on how to use it, but I found the class [XmlValueReference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/10.0/com/intellij/psi/impl/source/resolve/reference/impl/providers/XmlValueReference.java?av=h#XmlValueReference) which sounds useful. Yet again googling for "XmlValueReference" did not turn up anything useful on how to use the class. At least the [PSI Cookbook](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/PSI+Cookbook) tells me that I can find the Java class by using `JavaPsiFacade.findClass()`. I'd be thankful for any tutorials, hints and the like, that tell the correct usage.

The above linked discussion mentions that I need to call `registry.registerReferenceProvider(XmlTag.class, provider)` in order to register my provider once I eventually managed to implement it, but of which type is "registry" and where do I get it from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, here's a [nice tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Custom+Language+Support) that came up a few days ago, which explains the basics of IntelliJ plugin development (you should take a look at the section [Reference Contributor](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Reference+Contributor)).

You will likely have to define your own `PsiReferenceContributor`, which will be referenced in your `plugin.xml` like this:

```
<psi.referenceContributor implementation="com.yourplugin.YourReferenceContributor"/>
```

In your reference contributor, there's a method `registerReferenceProviders(PsiReferenceRegistrar)` where you will be able to call `registry.registerReferenceProvider(XmlTag.class, provider)`.

Finally, in your instance of `PsiReferenceProvider`, you will have to test the tag name to filter out tags which don't contain class references, then find [the right Java class](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5460579#5460579) using `JavaPsiFacade.findClass()`.

From my experience, the best place to get help regarding IntelliJ plugin development is [JetBrains' forums.](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development)