# IntelliJ IDEA plugin : Jump to declaration for custom xml

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have component based application. All of the components are defined in XML. The components may be defined in different xml files.

```
<!-- filename: components.xml -->

<components>
   <component type="x" name="y">
      <property1 attribute="attr"/>
      <property2 attribute="attr"/>
   </component>
   <component type="a" name="b">
      <property1 attribute="attr"/>
      …
   </component>
 </components>


<!-- filename: extra-components.xml -->
<components>
    <component type="x" name="z" extends="x:y">  <!-- this extends component x:y -->
        <property3 attribute="attr"/>
    </component>
</components>
```

Right now I'm trying to write a plugin so that I can jump from the child components to parent component. In the example above, the component type 'x' and name 'z' extends component type 'x' and name 'y'.

Going throughs some of the source from different plugins, I was able to add a menu item and grab content under the caret.

Say, if my caret is under "x:y" in second component, I can garb x and y so at least I can know the component type and component name to look for.

But I want to underline the contents under extends i.e. "x:y" when I press ctrl and search for the component and jump to the declaration of the component when ctrl+click like we jump to declaration of class.

I want guidance like which class should I look, how should I go or similar implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is a [reference contributor](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Reference+Contributor).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14376918/500478) for more details on how to set up a contributor. Once this contributor is created, I think you'll have two ways to find which XML element `x:y` refers to:

- parse every potential XML file and try to find a tag with the correct attributes, then return the corresponding PsiElement
- create an [index](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Indexing+and+PSI+Stubs+in+IntelliJ+IDEA) of every `component` tag, and lookup `x:y` in this index (requires much more work)