# ReferenceContributor don't works for existing languages

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to implements a new reference from an existing language, in case, PHP, but it even is catched from debugger. Seems that it just is not initialized.

**My problem is the following:** the Laravel Frameworks implements a concept called [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes). With that, when I do a method call like `$user->filterAge()` it, on reality, calls from a definition declared as `User::scopeFilterAge()` (*briefly*).

**What I want to do:** I like that PhpStorm understand that the "`filterAge`" points to `scopeFilterAge` declaration (*ctrl+click*). Like it does when I do at `$user`, for instance:

[image]

**What I tried:** I tried to follow the plugin development doc about [reference contribuitor](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/reference_contributor.html). Then I updated my `plugin.xml` with a new extension. Note: my inspections or completion contribuitors on this same file works fine. My problem is justly with this reference contribuitor over an existing language.

My **plugin.xml**:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <psi.referenceContributor language="PHP"
                              implementation="[...].ScopeReferenceContribuitor"/>
</extensions>
```

And the implementation of **ScopeReferenceContribuitor.java**:

```
public class ScopeReferenceContribuitor extends PsiReferenceContributor {
    @Override
    public void registerReferenceProviders(PsiReferenceRegistrar registrar) {
        // Breakpoint:
        [...]
    }
}
```

This breakpoint just don't works, never is called, nothing. Even if I force an error (like an `NPE`) it just don't works.

What I am forgiving?

---

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14376918/755393) seems solve my problem, but I already tested, and for some reason it just don't call the debugger on breakpoint.

I too [commited my code example](https://github.com/rentalhost/laravel-insight/commit/27c079c00642c0dbbccc480695a1458a87f6cf13).

Comment: are you using intelliJ or phpstorm?

Comment: Yes. On reality, it is a plugin that I am developing to IntelliJ/PhpStorm.

Comment: Sorry do bring this up so late, but I currently have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MegaIng I don't remember. But I thinks that I have implemented it as https://github.com/rentalhost/laravel-insight/commit/a9e1151be6f782a73cf9bc3ddc26208c608d045a